# Visual Studio 2022 17.8 cannot run .NET 6 website

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am running VS 2022 17.8.0 Preview 2.

My project is configured to target .NET 6.0.  When trying to run the app, I get an Http Error 500.30.

[image]

In the Output log, I get this message:

```
CoreCLR path = 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\coreclr.dll',
CoreCLR dir = 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\'
Loaded library from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\coreclr.dll
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
--- Invoked hostfxr_close [version: 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4 @Commit: 92959931a32a37a19d8e1b1684edc6db0857d7de]
```

I have uninstalled/reinstalled VS 2022 but that did not help.

Interestingly, if I run my application with .NET 8 as the Target Framework, the application will open.

Comment: Did you expect a preview release of Visual Studio to be bug free? Raise it with Microsoft and if you're lucky it may be fixed in preview 3.

Comment: I installed the stable version of 17.8 today, normal VS update cycle, and this error still exists!

Comment: For me it worked to manually install the .NET 7 SDK. It seems to be sufficient to have it installed. The target framework does not need to be changed on the project! 
Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Web-app-targeting-net50-stopped-working/10515999#T-N10518161

Comment: @jns 's solution worked for me too. Had the same problem with a .NET Core 3.1 project. After updating VS to 17.8 (stable) yesterday, this issue appeared...

Answer (score 0):

This release is now considered *stable*, I installed today and experienced the same issue.

- My project was .Net 5.0

Just as OP has reported, if you change the project target framework of just the ASP.Net project (don't change the dependencies and do not upgrade) then it works:

[image: Changed target framework]

---

The only change in the code that I had to make was to one of my compiler directives:

[image]

So while not technically an answer, with this workaround the rest of the application was stable (all other projects .Net 5) and worked without any further changes.